# IE 11, Modernizr and SCRIPT1002 syntax error

Tags: internet-explorer, ecmascript-6, modernizr

I have a site that use Modernizr for check if browser support es6.

I have this script:

```
 if (Modernizr.es6number) {
        Object.keys(objFiltri).map(key => objGrid_CustomFilter.perQuery[key] = objFiltri[key]);
    } else {
        labelsPrint.map(function (key) { objGrid_CustomFilter.perQuery[key] = objFiltri[key] });
    }
```

In IE11 the code

```
Modernizr.es6number
```

return false, but IE give me an error (SCRIPT1002 incorrect syntax) because doesn't recognize the es6 method .map.

My question is, if the **IF** return **FALSE**, why IE pass through the **TRUE** case? 
How can I avoid that?

Thank you!

Comment: include babel js in your code to write es6 syntax accept by all browser

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I can't include any other js file or anything else. :(

Comment: The syntax of es6 still not recognized by IE 11, i think so . To use polyfill, use babeljs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all the code doesn't check for ES6 support, it checks for support of one single feature.

More importantly you define an arrow function and IE doesn't support arrow functions. The whole(!) code is parsed before it get's executed. IE doesn't even get to the point where it checks `Modernizr.es6number`.

You cannot use syntax that is not supported by the browser. You cannot use arrow functions in IE 11.